# session expiry in symfony2

Tags: php, session, symfony

I am expiring the session in symfony2 by using the following code:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $this->maxIdleTime = ($this->container->getParameter('session_max_idle_time') > 0) ? $this->container->getParameter('session_max_idle_time') : 1200;

    if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {

        return;
    }

    $usr= $this->getUser();

    if (is_object($usr)) {

        if ($this->maxIdleTime > 0) {

        $this->session->start();
        $lapse = time() - $this->session->getMetadataBag()->getLastUsed();

            if ($lapse > $this->maxIdleTime) {

                $this->securityContext->setToken(null);
                $this->session->getFlashBag()->set('info', 'You have been logged out due to inactivity.');

            }
        }
    }

}
```

It correctly expires the session after a specific time, but the issue is, It does not expire the session instantly, but move on one step ahead on the page and when I hit back, It expires the session.

I can't understand what is the reason. Kindly help why It moves on next page and then from there it expires the session and went back to login page.

Comment: Have you tried `$this->session->invalidate();` after setting the token as null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after setting this resolved the issue.

$this->session->invalidate();